# I need to update my table by converting a column from int into date in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the column transe_date  from int  into  date ..

[image]

```
update fci
set fci.transe_date= convert(date,convert(varchar(8),transe_date));
```

Comment: The code should work fine. What is the issue?

Comment: You need to change he the data type of the column too. Changing the value of a column doesn't change its datatype. `UPDATE YourTable SET IntColumn = '1';` won't change the datatype of the column to a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a dummy column to hold data
2. Change data type of existing column
3. put all values back after converting using the column made
4. Drop the dummy column
5. Cleaning the new column

Script sample will be

```
/*1*/ 
Alter Table FCI
Add tempcol DateTime
Go
/*2*/
update fci
set tempcol = convert(date,convert(varchar(8),transe_date));

/*3*/ 
Alter Table FCI
alter column transe_date DateTime
Go


/*4*/
update fci
set transe_date = tempcol;


/*5*/ 
Alter Table FCI
drop column tempcol
Go
```

If the whole data is Date then directly converting the column type can do the job, the above process is the safe side process for start.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than creating a new column, completing an `UPDATE` statement, renaming your old column, and then the new, you could use 2 `ALTER` statements. You can't implicity convert an `int` to `date`, but you can implicitly convert an `int` to `varchar` and then from a `varchar` to a `date`:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (DateColumn int);

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (DateColumn)
VALUES (20160101),
       (20160307),
       (20180920);
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ALTER COLUMN DateColumn varchar(8);
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable
```

Of course, this ***assumes*** that all your ints are valid date values.

*Edit: If you do have values that aren't valid date values, you'll need to identify and correct these first. You could identify these by using `TRY_CONVERT`:*

```
SELECT YourIntColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(11),YourIntColumn)) IS NULL;
```

*There's no need to put a `TRY_CONVERT` on the `varchar(11)`, as an `int` can always be converted to a `varchar`. I used `varchar(11)` as well (instead of `varchar(8)`( because the largest value, in character length, you could have would be `-2147483648` (which is 11 characters long).*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the int values into dates, you will first have to add a new column (`transe_date2`) of that type. Then, you can store the converted values in this new column:

```
update fci
set fci.transe_date2 = convert(date,convert(varchar(8),transe_date));
```

Having done this, I suggest to use SSMS to drop the old column and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

```
--add date column
ALTER TABLE fci ADD transe_date2 date;
GO
--do conversions
UPDATE fci SET transe_date2=CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(8),transe_date),112);
GO
--drop int column
ALTER TABLE fci DROP COLUMN transe_date;
GO
--rename temporary column to transe_date
EXEC sp_rename 'fci.transe_date2', 'transe_date', 'COLUMN';
```